# Error in reading and writing data in sqlite database from iphone devide

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I have created one application, where I am storing the data into database and reading it. I have created a .sql file and added it into the resource folder. I can save and retrive the data over the simulator, my app is working fine over simulator but **when I install the same app over device I am getting error as "no such table"**.

Can anyone provide solution over this issue.

Here is the block of code that i m using:

/////// Inside AppDelegate.m >>Start>>>

///// to check the database exist or not >>>>

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TempDatabase.sql"];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath]; 

if(!success) {

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TempDatabase.sql"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];


    if (!success) 

        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);  

} else {

    NSLog(@"Database file found at path %@", dbPath);

}
```

/////// Inside AppDelegate.m <<

/////// Logic to write files in database >>> start>>

```
           sqlite3 *pDb; 
    char *databaseName; 

    databaseName = @"TempDatabase.sql";

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    //databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    databasePath =[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TempDatabase.sql"];

    //[self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];


    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &pDb) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {

        const char *sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO tablename (name) VALUES(?)";

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDb, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {


             sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [strTxtFldValue UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) 
        {
             NSLog( @"~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(pDb) );
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Name name is not added." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];

        } else {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation" message:@"name is added successfully." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];

                }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }

    sqlite3_close(pDb);
```

/////// Logic to write files in database <<

Comment: Odds are, you're accessing the database out of the bundle, vs copying it to read/write space in your post-install code.

Comment: I have added the database file to the resource folder and used the statement as: "databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"AppDatabase"ofType:@"sql"];"

Comment: Can you please provide the solution, above is the block of code that i m using.

Comment: In your AppDelegate, on entry to the app, you check whether the database exists in your private read/write directory.  If not, you copy it from the bundle.

Comment: @Hot Licks- I hv tried by this way also, but is not working at all.I hv shown popup in the AppDelegate to check wheather the database file is found or not, so shows the popup saying Database file found, but while inserting the values in the database it is not working.(But same code is working perfectly over simulator)

Comment: **WHERE** are you checking to see if it exists?  *Of course* it will exist in the bundle, but you can't write to that.  You need to check whether it exists in your private read/write directory.  (And note that you may need to delete and reinstall your app in order to clear out an old version of the DB in the read/write directory, to make your test work.)

Comment: @Hot Licks- I hv updated my code above, I M Checking whether the database exist or not in AppDelegate.m file. Here you suggest that I need to check whether it exists in private read/write directory, so how can I do that can you please provide the block of code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried by creating database at runtime. Execute the query at runtime and create the table, try this out this will definitely help you out.